# Twitch Button (HTML/JScript w bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, twitch, gwtbootstrap3

Hello everyone I've tried everything I can think of to make this work. I know it does return stream = null or active through use in the browser, but It will not apply my buttons to my page. Not so good with javascript can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

          var user_name, api_key;

      user_name = "Undead_Atomsk";
      api_key = "************************";

      twitch_widget.attr("href","https://twitch.tv/" + user_name);

      $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + user_name + '?client_id=' + api_key + '&callback=?', function(data) {
          if (data.stream) {
              document.write(<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/Undead_Atomsk" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn navbar-right">Live!</a>);
          } else {
              document.write(<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/Undead_Atomsk" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn navbar-right">Offline!</a>);
          }
      });

    })();
    </script
```

Comment: Use your browser's devtools: check console for errors in request, check request/response in the Network tab, look at what is Twitch API responding.

Answer (score 0):

Took your advice and used browser tools "Completely forgot about those".

I added this line to my html.

```
    <a href="" id="twitch-btn" class="navbar-right"></a>
```

I then made a .js file and used the following code everything works now the twitch API is just slow!

```
    (function() {

     var user_name, api_key, twitch_widget;

     user_name = "Undead_Atomsk";
     api_key = "********************";
     twitch_widget = $("#twitch-widget");

     twitch_widget.attr("href","https://twitch.tv/" + user_name);

     $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + user_name +'?client_id=' + api_key + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    if (data.stream) {
    document.getElementById("twitch-btn").innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/Undead_Atomsk" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn navbar-right">Live!</a>';
} else {
  document.getElementById("twitch-btn").innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/Undead_Atomsk" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right">Offline!</a>';
}
 });

 })();
```